# Ancient Triennial Cycle Today

Tags: minhag, torah-reading, communities

Are there any congregations who follow the ancient (Eretz Yisrael minhag) triennial cycle today, and so complete the Torah once every three years? I'm aware there are some Eretz Yisrael minhag revivalists out there; is this among the practices being revived?

Comment: The answer to your question [seems](/q/22202) to be yes. Unfortunately the user who asked that question doesn't seem to have been around of late, so I don't know that he'll stop by to answer yours. But I've posted a comment there, just in case. In any event, welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may, in particular, enjoy our more than 800 other [tag:minhag] questions.

Comment: @msh210 I think that question is more likely referring to the practice of many conservative synagogues where they read 1/3 of the current week's parsha, finishing the Torah in 3 years, but not in order. This is different from the ancient triennial cycle of reading straight through the Torah in 3 years

Comment: @Daniel, maybe it is. I guess if the answer to this question is yes, then that question may be referring to the old custom.

Comment: See [here](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14508-triennial-cycle) for a description of the practice in question, including super cool wheel-shaped reconstructed calendars.

Answer (score 5):

I heard from R. Nota Greenblatt (the eminent posek of Memphis and the greater South) that since the original enactment to read the Torah did not include the familiar rate of once a year, that in a case of need e.g. the baal korei has difficulty reading the whole parsha, then one could finish the Torah less frequently.  He implied that one would not even need to adopt the other ancient custom of completing it every three years, but one could instead choose a pace.

---

See also [here](http://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/sites/default/files/public/halakhah/teshuvot/19861990/moses_triennial.pdf) for a nice collection of sources, albeit from a non-Orthodox source.

Comment: Hello mevaqesh and welcome to mi.yodeya! Thanks for contributing your answer. I hope you find other places around the site where you can bring to bear some firsthand Rav Greenblatt insights.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, which was whether anyone uses the old triennial cycle.

Comment: Hello mevaqesh and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  As msh210 said, this doesn't seem to answer *this* question, which is asking who does this reading cycle.  Could I encourage you to instead post this answer on [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53057/472)?