# The Theme of the Parsha

Tags: parsha-torah-portion

Someone told me the following:

1) The events of the week correspond to the theme of that week's parsha,

2) The events in the parsha are manifested into the week.

Is there a source for this?

Comment: Sounds unlikely. The whole division of parshiyos is just a convention based on finishing the Torah every year. Those who didnt finish the Torah every year made their own system. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53057/are-there-any-leniencies-for-shortening-the-torah-reading-so-the-cycle-takes-mor

Comment: What you may be thinking is along the lines of the many that believe that whatever occurs in worldly events is because of G-d's hand and there are no "coincidences". I.e. each event is planned by G-d to occur at the exact time that it does. Those rabbis who understand this, and, perhaps, even those that don't completely understand it, nonetheless, attempt to correlate the events with some event, verse, or other message in the weekly Torah portion. If, for nothing else, it make for a meaningful Shabbat sermon (which in some shuls, is a form of "marketing" or "branding".)

Comment: LR used to frequently quote a Shalo"h (?) about yomim tovim being alluded to in the weekly parsha in which they occur.